# How to remediate TLS POODLE on IIS

Tags: tls, iis, configuration

I've been struggling to understand how to completely remediate TLS POODLE on IIS 7.5.

I've already disabled SSLv3 support for SSL POODLE. But according to the information that I've get from plenty of articles, bulletin, etc there is an another version of POODLE which called as "TLS POODLE".

As far as I understood TLS POODLE appears when CBC modes of ciphers enabled with TLS family.

Microsoft security bulletins says;

> "MS12-049 This security update resolves a publicly disclosed
>   vulnerability in TLS. The vulnerability could allow information
>   disclosure if an attacker intercepts encrypted web traffic served from
>   an affected system. All cipher suites that do not use CBC mode are not
>   affected." https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms12-jul

I've already applied the patched to the server. So the question is;

Do I need to completely disable CBC ciphers even if I've already deploy the KB2655992 update ? If the answer is yes then which ciphers do I need to enable ?

https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms12-jul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While SSL 3.0 POODLE is a design problem in the standard which thus affects all implementations TLS POODLE is an implementation problem only, that is implementations did not implement the TLS protocols properly.

According to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/3009008.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 (updated 04/2015) and https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2014/12/08/poodle-bites-tls IIS is not affected by TLS POODLE.